# Paper recommendation for 1200 dpi print?

Tags: paper, dpi, printer

I want to print out something really small for testing camera and lens resolution capabilities. I have a HP 4000 Laserprinter which is able to print at 1200 dpi. I am wondering what paper might be best suitable for my purpose?

Also I am wondering if glossy paper brings benefits here? The Internet is full of different paper all promising good quality, but which properties are most important to look at? I usually use only standard paper but this brings no benefit for 1200 dpi. I am afraid the ink is soaked too much.
I don't want to print this much so price does not matter in the end.

This is a sample image which I want to print, the lines should be at the distance as specified.

[image]

Comment: This is off topic, as are "shopping" type questions on most if not all Stack Exchange sites.  You can probably get a lot of information on various digital photography forums, as users there are likely to have experience.

Comment: Laser printers don't use ink, they use a dry toner which is fused to the paper by heat, so there should be no 'soak-up' spread at all.

Comment: @ZeissIkon other than one sentence which asked for a specific place to look (now removed!), I think this is a _good_ product recommendation question as it asks for "how to tell if this paper fits my purpose", along with a well-defined purpose. Good answers to this question should stand the test of time and still be relevant years from now; any bad answers which link to specific products, vendors etc can be downvoted or flagged appropriately by the community.

Comment: @PhilipKendall The close vote dialog specifically lets out "product recommendation" questions without qualification.  Perhaps someone should ask on our meta; if it's found to be allowable, it can always be reopened (assuming it even gets closed -- takes five votes or one super-mod).

Comment: @ZeissIkon I disagree :-) It specifically says "where the answer is likely to be either entirely personal or short-lived as a result of changing markets"; good answers to this question will not be entirely personal as they will apply to anybody wanting to print test charts, and will not be short-lived because paper technology isn't changing that fast.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I took that wording to mean that was generally the case, not as a qualification between one recommendation question and another.

Comment: for laser, it doesn't much matter. you want smooth, not textured. glossy might imply smooth, but for rez, it doesn't really matter, it's more a matter of aesthetics than performance.

Comment: @Thomas, as this is PS printer maybe it's wise to use vector source instead of bitmap. Based on my humble experience this will provide better resolution of the print. Do not forget to install PS driver in to the operating system you use.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Will check this out for sure. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Using a laser printed chart could limit your ability to tell really good lenses apart from great lenses. In [this article](https://petapixel.com/2013/10/11/perfect-lens-test-either/) Roger Cicala says, "It’s cheap and easy to buy an inkjet printed (or even home print) test chart and shoot Imatest. The reality is unless the chart is a high-quality linotype print (which are quite expensive — $400 to $1,000 each) the chart limits the program’s abilities."

Comment: He goes on in [the same article](https://petapixel.com/2013/10/11/perfect-lens-test-either/) to say, "Using a lesser chart doesn’t invalidate the results, but it certainly puts a ceiling on them. When some testers find a new, very sharp, very high resolution lens ‘isn’t much better’ than others they’ve tested, I sometimes wonder if they’re nearing the ceiling of their chart’s capabilities."

Comment: You may find this blog entry, [Setting Up an Optical Testing Station](https://www.lensrentals.com/blog/2014/02/setting-up-an-optical-testing-station/) from Roger Cicala at his own company website, lensrentals.com, interesting and helpful as well.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, finely printed details are created with photo lithography. The source image is created at a larger scale than the final image to reduce the effects of mechanical tolerances. The larger image is then optically reduced to the smaller final size.

In the extreme this is how silicon wafers are turned into semiconductor chips.

For a photographic test chart, the simplest method would be to use film to photograph an oversized original source image, and then to use traditional darkroom printing on a polyester paper to produce the test image at the desired size.

This would allow precision down to the fineness of silver crystals at the photographic and printing steps.

Ordinary computer system printing simply is not designed to that level of accuracy.

The 1200 dpi of a laser printer does not provide 1200 line pairs per inch. It is designed to provide high quality output at a nominal 300 or 600 dpi by filling in the spaces between dots.

Films designed for microfilm work are still available. That would be a good base material for high precision work.

Of course the requirements may be over specified. In that case, it is probably best to empirically test available papers and printers to see what best fits the job because paper is a highly variable material at small scales.

In addition, Mylar or other plastic media might be a better substrate for test images due to higher dimensional stability with changes to temperature and humidity. Again, testing is warranted if such things matter.

Comment: Small remark: as all the lines are horizontal and vertical the resolution of the printer do not need to be reduced as there is no need for dithering the lines.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, you mention polyester paper might be used in a darkroom printing, I can see polyester based paper is available in special stores, so this might be worth a try.

Comment: @RomeoNinov It is not dithering. Assuming dotsare approximately circular and ordinary features are wider than 1/300 inch, the “extra” dots solve close packing by creating overlap. This creates more uniform density of infill areas and hence better typography. In your vertical and horizontal scenario, the “extra” dots make the edges crisper.